# Not able to open a file in read mode in c

Tags: c

```
char fileName[20];
    puts("Enter the date.\n");
    scanf("-> %s", fileName);

    //Read the file
    FILE *ptr;
    ptr = fopen(fileName, "r");

    if(ptr == NULL)
    {
        printf("\nNo file was found with this name\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\nI FOUND the file.\n");
    }

    fclose(ptr);
```

I just want the user to enter a file name and then display 'found the file' as of now however even when the this code file and the text file are in same directory I am always getting the message'No file was found with this name' and I assure you that I am inputting the right file name(along with .txt extension).

Comment: What did you enter? Your `scanf` string looks odd. Do you really expect the user to enter `->`?

Comment: Do proper error checking. Check the return value of `scanf`. Also , do basic debugging - use a debugger or even just debug print statements to examine the `fileName` variable.

Comment: The '->' is an arrow to tell the user to enter the value. Anyway, I entered the value 'a.txt'.

Comment: @kaylum I really dont't know how to debug the program. can you suggest some learning source.

Comment: That's not how `scanf` works. The format string in `scanf` tells it to look for that user input. If the user doesn't enter that, `scanf` will fail. Try `scanf("%s", fileName)`

Comment: `scanf` isn't going to print the `->` characters. It's going to require them on input. Always check the value that `scanf` returns (read the documentation to see what that value tells you). And once you get things working, you'll want to learn about the danger of using a `%s` format with `scanf`.

Comment: @kaylum  ohh man! That worked. Thank you

Comment: @Abhishek "*The '->' is an arrow to tell the user to enter the value*" Do you see that arrow when you enter the value? If not, then you should wonder what happened to it, and realize it's not used as a prompt.

Comment: *can you suggest some learning source*. A search engine. Seriously, being able to do your own basic research is an essential skill.

Comment: For future reference, when you post a question please provide a [mre] if at all possible. We should be able to copy-and-paste the code from your question and run it ourselves without having to add anything (like a definition of `main` or the required `#include <stdio.h>`). It's ok this time, but if you don't know what the problem is, you can't be sure what information you can safely leave out.

Comment: @KeithThompson Roger that, Sir

Comment: `if(ptr == NULL) { perror(fileName); exit(EXIT_FAILURE);}` Although in this case that is still undefined behavior since `scanf` most likely did not assign a value and `fileName` is uninitialized.  You must *always* check the value returned by scanf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @kaylum I got the answer.

The problem is with the `scanf()` statement. The `scanf("-> %s", fileName)` statement wants the user to input only `->` otherwise it will fail.